# How do I subclass argparse.Action to add a custom action?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subclass, argparse

I have a command line script I'm trying to run that inserts a default value into the Namespace if the value is absent, or takes the supplied argument as is if it's present.

So I want to do this:

```
myscript.py --merge
```

Would result in the argument parser Namespace looking like this:

```
Namespace(merge='--merge')
```

Else, if I call

```
myscript.py
```

Namespace should look like this:

```
Namespace(merge='DONTMERGE')
```

I think I need to subclass the `argparse.Action` class's `__call__` method to perform a custom action as specified here: https://pymotw.com/2/argparse/ but I'm unable to figure out how to do this.

I thought something like this would do the trick:

```
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if isinstance(self.values, None):
            self.values = 'NOMERGE'
        else:
            self.values = '--nomerge'
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: Why not just use a `store_const` argument?

Comment: I tried store_const, the problem is I would then have to supply an additional argument to --merge, like myscript --merge someotherarg the arguments supplied through the command line are piped to another script elsewhere that I cannot change the behaviour of.

Comment: Looking at the linked article, the `setattr` call should be indented one level deeper.

Comment: @FamousJameous that was a typo, sorry. Have corrected now.

Comment: Look at the `_StoreConstAction` class in the `argparse.py`.  A regular `store` Action with `nargs='?'` is also useful.  It sets values 3 ways - `default`, `const`, and argument.

Comment: Try setting `nargs` to 0 so your custom class doesn't get or require an argument.  All subclasses of Action customize the `__init__` as well as the call.

Comment: @hpaulj I overrode just the `__call__` method and was able to get the functionality I wanted. I did have to set `nargs=0` like you've advised when I did that, but I could also override `__init__` and set `self.nargs=0` to get around that. Your method is much better. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need a normal `store_const` argument.

```
parser.add_argument('--merge', action='store_const', const='MERGE', default='DONTMERGE')
```

If you call your script with `--merge`, the `merge` argument takes the value `MERGE` (specified above as `const`). Otherwise, the `merge` argument takes the value `DONTMERGE` (specified above as `default`).

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the possibility of storing a default value. This looks like it has done the trick.

If you have a suggestion on how to do this with subclassing then I would really appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The exact thing that you request is impossible to implement by subclassing `Action`.  The reason is `CustomAction` instance is `__call__`'ed ***if and only if*** `--merge` is passed to the argument parser:

```py
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("Yay, I've been called")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--merge', nargs='?', action=CustomAction)

print(p.parse_args([]))
print(p.parse_args(['--merge']))
```

```
Namespace(merge=None)
Yay, I've been called
Namespace(merge=None)
```

Here I had to pass `nargs='?'`, otherwise *argparse* requires an argument for `--merge`.

Many `Action`s override [`Action.__init__(...)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Lib/argparse.py#L820), but it has no access to parser's Namespace  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

If you want to go all the way with the subclasses, you'll probably have to subclass `ArgumentParser` itself and modify `add_argument()` method.

One could do some pretty cool and/or weird stuff with Actions, though:

```py
class ReverseAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, ''.join(reversed(values)))


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--string', action=ReverseAction)

print(p.parse_args(['--string', '12345']))
```

```
Namespace(string='54321')
```

*(The only time I created a subclass of `argparse.Action` myself was to implement advanced validation)*

---

As for your particular case, it looks to me like a job for a simple `action='store_true'`:

```py
>>> parser.add_argument('--merge', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--merge'], dest='merge', nargs=0, const=True,
default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--merge'])
Namespace(merge=True)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(merge=False)
```

…or even a `BooleanOptionalAction` (in Python >=3.9):

```py
>>> parser.add_argument('--merge', action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False)
BooleanOptionalAction(option_strings=['--merge', '--no-merge'], dest='merge', nargs=0,
const=None, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(merge=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--no-merge'])
Namespace(merge=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--merge'])
Namespace(merge=True)
```

As usual, see [*argparse* docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and/or source code =)